Is it possible to add markers to label the values used to xOffset a bar chart?
Consider the example from the gallery for a bar chart that has xOffset set in order to "internally group" each set of bars: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart2.html
Here, the labels for the xOffset are shown in the legend.
If I was using color for something else however, how could I go about marking the Group values on the x-axis? This answer achieves the effect using facets, but I'm wondering if I can avoid that and still have the Group values displayed on the x-axis?
